# Riddle 3:What am I?

Tags: riddle

I have cities, but not houses. I have rivers, but not water. I have forests, but not trees. I have mountains but not rocks.What am I?

Comment: This riddle is not yours, by the way (see [here](http://www.puzzlesandriddles.com/Riddle17.html) or [here](https://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/teaser.php?op=2&id=351&comm=0)). Please include where and how you came across this riddle, or one of the links (or similar links) I have provided.

Comment: i found it from kids' magazine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you:

> A map?

Because

> Maps have pictorial representations of all the things listed, but are never made of houses, water, trees, and rock.

Answer (score 3):

`What am I?`

> A **globe**?

It fits the description perfectly.

---

**Edit:**

Looking at the other answers, there seems to be more than one answer to this riddle.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Yours is just as good :D (+1)

Comment: Wrong answer...

Comment: @hahaboki it might not be the *intended* answer, but how is it *wrong*? Does it not fit the riddle’s description? :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simply just a

> Map. Fits exactly as the riddle says

Comment: Good answer,but you aren't the first

Comment: Indeed, I am not though it was very close :D @hahaboki

Comment: I was thinking of awarding your answer a $50$ rep bounty (because it is the accepted answer, although it isn't accepted) but for some reason, I can't. I can only award from $100$ rep or over. Do you know why this is the case? xD Have I awarded too many bounties?

Comment: @user477343 you may be too generous in this site :D

Comment: Well, I must say, it would kinda suck to have the correct answer but then not get accepted because you are at least $3$ seconds too slow :\

Comment: @user477343 Nah, as long as I know that my answer is just as correct, I'm fine :D

Comment: @KevinL if I were you, I wouldn't mind either; but most people just view the accepted answer and disregard other answers, whether they be correct or not. Glad you're fine, though :P

Comment: @user477343 Yeah, I guess that's kinda true :D

Comment: This is off-topic, but I'm just curious, do you like math(s)? I like maths, and I've been working on something known as a "conjecture". Are you familiar with what they are? I'd like to show you and see your thoughts if so. (I ask because I noticed you've joined the Mathematics Stack Exchange.) :D

Comment: @user477343 Well, I do like math a lot, but I don't really have a lot of knowledge on conjectures. I think they are just unproven mathematical theories. :D

Comment: @KevinL yeah, you got it. Do you like square numbers and Fibonacci numbers? :P

Comment: @user477343 Yeah, I find them interesting, I guess ;D

Comment: Well, I assume you like puzzles, so would you like to continue this discussion in chat? :P

Comment: @KevinL Well [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82585/thesimplifires-chatroom) might serve well for your suggestion :D .... wait, where did the comment go? xD

Comment: @user477343 Oh, I just knew a chatroom like that exists. Nice!